# COBOL- Add number of characters to a string based on variable

Tags: cobol

How would I add characters to the beginning of a string based on a variable? For example a vendor we use for telephone numbers converts out string to a numeric which drops the leading 0's off of the phone number. When they send us the report back we convert the number back into a string but now it doesn't have the correct amount of numbers. I'm trying the following:

```
IF LENGTH(TO-NUM) < 10
    SUBTRACT LENGTH(TO-NUM) FROM 10 GIVING ADD-NUM-ZERO
```

Now I need to figure out how to add ADD-NUM-ZERO number of 0's to the beginning of the string TO-NUM without overwriting the characters already at the beginning.

Comment: Did you intend `> 10` or did you mean `< 10`?

Comment: What is the `data description entry` for `TO-NUM`?

Comment: Yes I did, thank you I edited it. TO-NUM PIC X (16).
Extra characters are given for the dashes and parenthesis.

Comment: Would not `function length (to-num)` always return `16`? And, what is a representative data value for `to-num`; is it a series of digits followed by spaces?

Comment: Is the `10` the count of all characters except spaces, or does it mean only the digits `0 thru 9`?

Comment: Ok, my fault. I gave you some incorrect info. TO-NUM is PIC X (10). after I add the leading 0's back on I move it to another variable that is PIC X (16). Apologizes for the confusion.
The length function < 10 would be the check to see if the vendor dropped the leading zeros.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687073/how-to-replace-spaces-at-the-right-into-zeros-at-the-left-in-cobol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `TO-NUM` contains only digits followed by spaces (or spaces followed by digits), then

```
1 TO-NUM PIC X(10).
1 temp-x.
 5 temp-9 pic 9(10).

if to-num not numeric
    compute temp-9 = function numval (to-num)
    move temp-x to to-num
end-if
```

will, if necessary, replace the previous content with the same value but with leading zeros.

The `IF TO-NUM NOT NUMERIC` statement is equivalent to asking if the number of digits in `TO-NUM` is less than 10.

For example, if `to-num` was `'5551212   '` before, then `to-num` will be `'0005551212'` after.

If `to-num` contains non-digits, then it would be necessary to extract the digits by parsing `to-num` into `temp-9`.

Comment: TO-NUM only contains digits, so using the numval function would add the appropriate number of leading zeros?

Comment: @Rick: the note should be "assuming ... contains only digits followed by or following spaces".

Comment: @JackT - If `TO-NUM` 'only contains digits', then it will contain precisely 10 digits and `function numval` will not change the value. This means there is no need to check for the number of digits. However, it is considered 'best practice' to validate the content of  `TO-NUM` since it comes from an outside source.

Comment: @JackT The `NUMVAL` function creates an intermediate numeric item stripping the leading zeroes, stopping at the first non-digit (the maximum digits the intermediate item can hold depend on your vendor but should at least be 18), by `MOVE`ing it to another numeric item (in this case `temp-9`) you strip the leading zeroes of it that are bigger than the item can hold (in Rick's sample: 10).
Using the alphanumeric group gives you an item which will be space-filled on the right side.
When you need multiple sizes use multiple definitions.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - The context of the question is digits followed by spaces, but I will add a parenthetical comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Working-storage section.
   01 NUM    PIC 9(10) COMP-5.
   01 TELNUM-G.
     03 TELNUM PIC 9(10).
     03 TELNUM-S REDEFINES TELNUM.
       05 AREACODE   PIC 999.
       05 THREEDIGIT PIC 999.
       05 FOURDIGIT  PIC 9999.
   01 TELOUTPUT PIC X(13) VALUE '(AAA)TTT-NNNN'.

   Procedure division.
       Move 31234 to NUM.

       MOVE NUM TO TELNUM.
       INSPECT TELOUTPUT
         REPLACING ALL 'AAA' BY AREACODE
                   ALL 'TTT' BY THREEDIGIT
                   ALL 'NNNN' BY FOURDIGIT
```

This code assume the number is in "NUM", and it can be in any of ZONE/PACK/BINARY/COMP-3/COMP-5 formats.  I've used COMP-5 in this example code.